# Webpack html plugin delete causes landing page to return 'Cannot GET /'

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, webpack-4

The application setup runs as expected when served.

But when I update the `vue.config.js` with:

```
chainWebpack: config => {
    config.plugins.delete('html')
    config.plugins.delete('preload')
    config.plugins.delete('prefetch')
}
```

and serve the project it lands:
[image]

It works as expected when the `vue.config.js` file just has:

```
chainWebpack: config => {
    config.plugins.delete('preload')
    config.plugins.delete('prefetch')
}
```

It works as expected